# grpc call consumption in smartpy

Tags: smartpy, rpc

we have done a grpc call consumption in python. now for our smart contract wanted to consume one grpc call. is it possible in smartpy.
Unable to found any example till date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SmartPy creates smart contracts. Smart contracts don’t directly interact with the outer world.

You need to send data yourself or with an oracle.

Comment: Thanks FFF. Were thinking in wrong direction previously

Comment: can you give more detail about what is mean't by send data yourself?

Comment: You can send a transaction to then contract with the appropriate payload.